# How does pg_advisory_lock work in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to use `pg_advisory_lock` with typeorm but it doesn't work.

```js
const insert = async (id: number) => {
  const connection = getConnection()
  const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner()
  await queryRunner.connect()
  await queryRunner.startTransaction()
  try {
    await getManager().query(`SELECT pg_advisory_lock(${id})`)
    // select...
    // insert...
    // update...
    const re = await getManager().query("SELECT mode, classid, objid FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid() AND locktype = 'advisory';")
    // [ { mode: 'ExclusiveLock', classid: 0, objid: 1 } ]
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
    return // ...
  } catch (e) {
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
    throw new Error(e)
  } finally {
    await queryRunner.release()
  }
}
```

And after executing the function, we try to execute the request separately

```sql
SELECT mode, classid, objid FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid() AND locktype = 'advisory';
```

answer:
[image: .]

Comment: Perhaps the session that took the lock has terminated since.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Then, logically, the race-condition should not be fulfilled

Comment: I don't understand. What I mean is that an advisory lock doesn't outlive the database session.

Comment: You have not described a race condition.